# Printing a value in textbox when clicked view after selection

Tags: php

I have a page that selects value from different tables, when I select a class corresponding divisions are displayed (I used javascript) but when I click the view button I want all the values selected to be displayed. I am done with all the value including class, but corresponding division doesnot get displayed. since I am not much eficient in php, cant find out how, plz do help.

Here is my code that displays class in the textbox when selected.

```
<div class="field">
```

Class:

```
<div id="combo" style="width:20px;">
   <select name="class" id="class" onChange="getDivision(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <?php 
         $select3="select * from ".TABLE_CLASS."";
         $res=mysql_query($select3);
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
      ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>" <?php if($row['ID']==@$_POST['class']){ ?> selected="selected"<?php }?>><?php echo $row['class'];?></option>
      <?php 
         }
      ?>
   </select>
</div>
</div>
<!--<div id="aa"></div>-->
<div class="field">
```

Division:

```
<div id="combo" style="width:20px;">
    <select name="division" id="division" >
       <!--<option value="">Select</option>-->
       <option value="<?php echo $row['division'];?>"></option>                 
    </select>
 </div>
<!--<input type="text" name="a" id="a">-->
</div>
</div> <!-- /login-fields -->
```

Comment: You are saying the you its not displaying anything in the division drop down menu?? m i correct

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['division'];?>"></option>
```

You got nothing in those line between option tag. Put some thing there i am using $row['division']. just to show you that you are missing that

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['division'];?>"><?php echo $row['division'];?></option>
```